# Set struct field of pointer type

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, set

The task is pretty simple. I have struct for model Foo, and one for it's representation:

```
type Foo struct {
  FooId string
  Bar   string
  Baz   *string
  Salt  int64
}

type FooView struct {
  FooId *string `json: "foo_id"`
  Bar   *string `json: "bar"`
  Baz   *string `json: "baz"`
}
```

As you may see, there is Salt field which I want to hide, change JSON field names, and do all the fields optional. The target method should fill FooView using Foo like this:

```
func MirrorFoo(foo Foo) (*FooView, error) {
  return &FooView{
    FooId: &foo.FooId,
    Bar:   &foo.Bar,
    Baz:   foo.Baz,
  }, nil
}
```

And now, I want to do the same with Go reflect:

```
func Mirror(src interface{}, dstType reflect.Type) (interface{}, error) {
  zeroValue := reflect.Value{}
  srcValue := reflect.ValueOf(src)
  srcType := srcValue.Type()
  dstValue := reflect.New(dstType)
  dstValueElem := dstValue.Elem()
  for i := 0; i < srcType.NumField(); i++ {
    srcTypeField := srcType.Field(i)
    srcValueField := srcValue.FieldByName(srcTypeField.Name)
    dstField := dstValueElem.FieldByName(srcTypeField.Name)

    // if current source field exists in destination type
    if dstField != zeroValue {
      srcValueField := srcValue.Field(i)
      if dstField.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && srcValueField.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {

        panic("???")

      } else {
        dstField.Set(srcValueField)
      }
    }
  }
  return dstValue.Interface(), nil
}
```

This code works fine when FooId is uuid.UUID in both types, but it fails when source is uuid.UUID and destination is *uuid.UUID, and now do not know how to overcome this.

Somehow I need to do analog of dstField.Set(reflect.ValueOf(&uuid.UUID{}...)) bit everything I've tried does not works. Any ideas?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Addr

Comment: try `sourceValueField.Addr()` to get a pointer to the source value.

Comment: Keep in mind that Addr will panic if Value is not addressable, e.g. field is not exported, etc. so before calling Addr call CanAddr to find out whether or not you can call Addr. If CanAddr returns false but you still need a pointer to an *equivalent* value then make a copy of the non-addressable value with reflect.Copy and call Addr on that copy.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Addr() worked for me, but without

```
reflect.Copy()
```

It's for arrays. I've instantiated new value using reflect.New() and .Set() current value. Address became available. It's completely black magic. Thanks for all.